# Ruby plugin configuration inside IntelliJ

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

I have the latest 15.0.2 IntelliJ, and a fairly simple set of Ruby scripts inside a /scripts/ folder in a Scala project.  Syntax highlighting works correctly, but for some reason, IntelliJ is complaining it can't find basic things like `File.open` AND `File.dirname`.  The scripts themselves work perfectly (I run them outside of IntelliJ as part of an external process), but somehow IntelliJ thinks their syntax is wrong.

Where can I configure the Ruby plugin inside IntelliJ? It's not obvious at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a Ruby interpreter defined?

(Disclaimer - I'm running 14.1.5, but it *should* be similar, if not the same)

You can do this in File > Project Structure > Platform Settings > SDKs. You should see a window like the this:

[image: Platform SDKs]

Once that is done, or if you've already set that up previously, make sure that the project is set to use the Ruby interpreter you've specified.

In the same popup, go to Project Settings > Project, and choose the correct SDK from the dropdown.

[image: Project SDK]

Comment: Note : Ruby plugin for Intellij IDE is available only when you have Ultimate Edition of Intellij IDE . You won't be able to install in Community edition . See this for mode detail (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/ruby-plugin.html)